# Convert list to dictionary, with key and value from list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Sorry if a repeated question, new to programming couldn't find any appropriate answer. I am trying to convert a list to dictionary. key  being x[1] and values as x[2]

Just to be clear I have a n*3 array and need to convert it to a dictionary with 2nd column as keys and 3rd column as values.

I tried:

```
for entry in data:
     keys=entry[1]
     values=entry[2]

source = dict.fromkeys(keys, values)
```

got error 'type list not hashable'

Went through question 4576115. However, I need to iterate through each element of a 3000+ *3 array with most elements themselves being list and thereafter setting the 2nd element of each entry as a key and the 3rd as a value. just to amplify, also tried

```
b = {data[i][1]: data[i][2] for i in range(0, len(data))}
```

and  for entry in data:

```
keys=entry[1]
values=entry[2]
b.update(keys,values)
```

and

```
keyList.append(keys)
valueList.append(values)
b = dict(zip(keyList,valueList))
```

and

```
b={entry[1]:entry[2] for entry in data}
```

same issue- error 'list' not hashable

OK sorry. Got it. The issue is that the key themselves are lists. I was looking at the array and missed the element

Comment: Do you mean you have a long list, where every two indices is a key:value pair?
[k1, v1, k2, v2, k3, v3, ...]

Comment: Who is voting to reopen? This is a clear duplicate.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of question 4576115.

Comment: @RichieHindle Only in that that answers for this are slightly simpler.

Comment: @Marcin reread each question, the initial state is different. This is not a duplicate of 4576115.

Comment: @cmd So what? The solutions are substantially the same; the only difference here is that the solutions omit a step.

Comment: @Marcin except that those answers dont answer this question, sure they are exactly the same.  I am sure this question or one more similar has been asked, find that one to dup it. duping this one with the wrong answers is less then useful

Comment: @cmd Well, I think they do answer this question.

Comment: Could you please show us the structure of "DATA"?
if the item you want is the key of the dictionary is a list lists does not not have a hash, you can do is convert the list to a tuple, tuples have hashes.

Answer (score 8):

Did not quite understand, but would not this what you want?

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,5,6]]
>>> b = {x[1]:x[2] for x in a}
>>> b
{2: 3, 3: 4, 5: 6}
>>>
```

Comment: Sequence assignment is usually preferable.

Comment: that form the code runs faster:
http://pythonfasterway.uni.me/#test24

Comment: Apart from that site being hideously unusable, you're comparing apples to oranges. Try actually comparing similar things: `{x[1]:x[2] for x in a}` to `{k:v for x,k,v in a}`

Comment: you're right unpacking is even faster!
tidy in http://pythonfasterway.uni.me/#test24

Comment: My testing shows that unpacking is *very slightly* slower: http://ideone.com/WoYGf4 However, to choose based on this kind of time difference is the definition of premature optimization.

Comment: strange my tests show the opposite:
pythonfasterway.uni.me/#test24

Comment: Possibly you're using a different version of python. Again, that's another reason not to prematurely optimise this.